# New entries only searchable by title field

Tags: search, index, reindex

I've recently done an upgrade of our site and am having issues with finding entries in the admin.
I keep entries for people who register a product so we have fields like registrationSerial and registrationSurname. registrationSerial is special as I use it as the title.

Since the upgrade I can only find new entries if I search with the serial number. If I try to use the surname it only finds entries from before.

As part of the upgrade I moved from using sproutforms to using freeform, they take care of creating the entries from a form on the site. I've ruled out this being the issue as the search isn't isn't fixed if I edit and save an entry in the admin, so at that point it should refresh the index with he new values.

I've also checked the fields and they are all set to "Use this field’s values as search keywords".

Comment: Can you try rebuilding your search indexes? They could be out of date: https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/searching.html#rebuilding-your-search-indexes

Comment: I tried on my test site and didn't make any difference, but isn't me saving a single item enough to rebuild its index?

Comment: "isn't me saving a single item enough to rebuild its index?" just for that single item. what are some examples of "registrationSerial" and "registrationSurname" that you're searching for?

Comment: An example registrationSerial is "12345T3500001", I think that works OK as this field is used for the title. An example registrationSurname is anybody's last name, like "Jones".

If I search for Jones I get all entries before November when I updated the site. If I take a recent entry with the surname Jones and save it then is still doesn't show up in the search results.